# What's a good free MySQL admin tool?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I'm looking at phpMyAdmin to manage users and create the database in the first place. Is it the best thing to go for, or are there other packages that are not web based that might be faster or better? I come from Postgres where pgAdmin III did everything I needed. Is there a free equivalent for MySQL? I am using it on OS X 10.6.2 server. I don't mind paying (a bit) if it's worth it, but I prefer free. It's for a personal server.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/), it's the successor of the good old CocoaMySql.

It's **free** and **open-source** and the interface is just great! Give it a try and you will hardly come back!

Answer (score 6):

personally i like the official mysql tools best!

[Mysql Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html)

quoting from their website:

> MySQL Workbench provides DBAs and developers an integrated tools environment for:
>
> - Database Design & Modeling
> - SQL Development (replacing MySQL Query Browser)
> - Database Administration (replacing MySQL Administrator)

Comment: I hear you - that's why I liked the official Postgres admin tool too.

Answer (score 3):

There is Navicat for MySQL Lite edition which is free for non-commercial use if you're looking for a non-web app.

Comment: I've used it before. Very similar to the MS Sql Managemenet tool in some aspects.

Comment: Navicat is nice, but has its own ideas about character encoding charsets. It appears that the gridview component it uses tries to 'magically' fix incorrectly encoded characters such as utf8 retrieved as latin1. While I actually *want* it to show the two bytes that make up the utf8 char, it 'fixes' this by showing the single utf8 char. Also, if there's a corrupt character in a record, it displays the record as all blank. As a result Navicat is not fit to debug encoding issues. We use phpmyadmin for that.

Answer (score 1):

SQLYog is pretty handy and has both commercial ($$) and community editions.

- Commercial - http://www.webyog.com/en/
- Community/open source - http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/

SequelPro for OS X is also nice - http://www.sequelpro.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Valentina Studio](http://www.valentina-db.com) is available on Windows, Linux and Mac OS X and it is free. It also handles Postgre, SQLite and Valentina DB (an object-relational, columnar db) as well as MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching for something like this: [MySQL Workbench](http://mysql.com/products/workbench/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Mac OS X, I **highly** recommend CocoaMySQL, available at http://cocoamysql.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: k thanks Jason - but the project has been abandoned. I'll play with its replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Give **HeidiSQL** a try on Windows.